# Filter View by Entity Reference Value From Current Node

Tags: views, entities

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, I believe that this should be easy but I still can't solve it. I'm a beginner at this. -_-

**I have 3 Content types**

1. Venue
2. Food
3. Package

I have a List of Venue that will be used as reference for the Food. So, The Food content type has an entity reference field -> field_venue

**The Food will only be available to the venue it referenced.**

The **Package** Content type has the entity reference **Venue** and **Food**. It shows the venue and the food available.

I use **Entity Reference View Widget** for the Entity reference on Package Content Type. The Venue is working well.

**My Problem is the Food.**

I need an Entity Reference View Widget (VIEW) that **shows the available food for the Venue**.

On the form, the user will only be able to answer the **Venue field**. After that the form will be **saved** and the entity reference field for Food will display on the page, that is the place where the user will answer that field.

On the entity reference view widget **Food**, I have the following:

**Filter Criteria:**
Content Type: Food

**Relationship:**
Entity Reference: Referenced Entity (field_venue) marked as required

The **problem is that the view shows all the food even if the chosen venue is not available for that food**. I don't know where to put that condition. Either on contextual filter or Filter Criteria. I'm not sure. I just need the view to get the **Answer of the Venue** from that same form/node so that the Food will **filter automatically**.

Is there anyone that will be able to help?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working with this set up:

**Contextual Filter**: field_venue
-> Provide default value
 ->PHP Code
  -> PHP contextual filter code

> $node=menu_get_object();
>   return $node->field_venue_for_catering['und'][0]['target_id'];

- "field_venue" is the venue field from "Food"
- "field_venue_for_catering" is the venue field from "Package".

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but you could try adding a filter criterion on Venue to the Food View and expose the criterion.  That way the user can filter Food *manually* in the widget.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried that. But I think the form will become redundant..? because the user will need to choose the venue twice. But thank you for your suggestion! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I needed to filter a view based on a Taxonomy field in a content type. I found a way to do that and it's very easy.

1- make a contextual filter -> select provide default value.

2- select type -> Taxonomy term id from url, you will get new checkboxes appeared below it.

3- check the following:  Load default filter from term page,  Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks, Limit terms by vocabulary.

4- select the Vocabulary you want to filter based on.

5- Multiple-value handling: Filter to items that share all term.